# .net Web Site Administration Tool not creating membership database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to complete this walkthrough 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879kf95c.aspx

When it comes time to use the Web Site Administration Tool it displays the following error when I click on the security tab

> There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused
>   by an invalid server name or credentials, or by insufficient
>   permission. It can also be caused by the role manager feature not
>   being enabled. Click the button below to be redirected to a page where
>   you can choose a new data store.
>
> The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: Unable to
>   connect to SQL Server database

.

Nothing was added to the web.config file, and there is nothing in the App_Data folder.

I have added a small section to the web.config file enabling the role manager but it has not changed anything, I am not sure how to check the invalid server name and credentials.

Comment: What does your connection string look like?

Comment: There was nothing created in the web.config file, I was under the impression that the database was supposed to be created automaticly

Comment: You must first have a DB to hold the necessary tables. I forget the exact process, but I remember having to run `aspnet_regsql.exe` to get everything to work. [Here's a link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649314.aspx) I found, scroll to step 3 for information regarding DB registration. `aspnet_regsql.exe` can be found in your `Windows` folder, just run a search.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I have already used this tool and created the correct database, and this is generally what I am trying to learn for my application, although this does not solve my problem. I have found this post on another forum, I think the author explains his problem better http://forums.asp.net/t/1828154.aspx?Web+Site+Administration+Tool+Does+Not+Create+ASPNETDB+Data+Base unfortunately his solution does not apply to me since I have a sql server 2012 installation